# PHP - How can i check that a file is in a specific directory?

Tags: php, file, path, directory

I have a given path like

```
directory1/directory2/directory3/file.txt
```

i would like to check if this path is in the directory2. But only searching with strpos is not enough because the path could be

```
directory1/directory2/../directory4/file.txt
```

How can i check that the given path is located in a given directory?

Comment: check the path first if it existing using `is_dir` or `file_exists` if it exists then proceed with your process

Comment: I do not want to know if the path `directory2/directory2/../directory4/file.txt` exists. i want to know if the file is located in the `directory2`. Because with `..` the user could go out of my upload directory and see some critical files.

Answer (score 0):

This checks in directory exists otherwise creates a one

```
if (!file_exists("directory2/directory2/../directory4")) 
 mkdir("directory2/directory2/../directory4", 0777);


if (file_exists("directory2/directory2/../directory4")) 
 if(file_exists("directory2/directory2/../directory4/file.txt"))
   echo "file exist"
 else
    echo "file not found";
else
  echo "directory not found";
```

Comment: I do not want to know if the path `directory2/directory2/../directory4/file.txt` exists. i want to know if the file is located in the `directory2`. Because with `..` the user could go out of my upload directory and see some critical files.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path to the file.

Example :

```
$filename  = "/var/www/projecname/files/file.txt"
if(file_exists($filename))
{
 ....
}
```